# Passing value of input field from one page to another page

Tags: jsf, variables, facelets

I found several similar questions but none of them was helpful as they referred rather to passing variable to beans and nothing else.

I have a page ("RegistrationStep1.xhtml") with a text field which value I would like to pass to the second page ("RegistrationStep2.xhtml") as a part of more complex form (for example - the 1st and only text field is for login, users submit form, there is some processing between pages to check if login is available and if so, the 2nd page is loaded with more comples form - login (completed from 1st page), password etc).

I am knew to JSF and already have tried several solution of which none worked.

Comment: You could use the same page and extend the form with `rendered=#{  }` on a JSF-element surrounding the second part of the form. This way you won't need to redirect to a second page. Offcourse, if you've got a reason to use a second page, this won't be of use.

Answer (score 0):

There is special bean scope @ConversationScope which is useful to wizards. Read this [How does JSF 2 ConversationScope work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788430/how-does-jsf-2-conversationscope-work)