# How to reset in jsf?

Tags: jsf, liferay, facelets, portlet

I am using liferay and jsf. In my portlet I tried to reset after submitting page by setting new values to the backing bean. I got blank fields but when I refreshed the page, I got my old values again which I have submitted earlier and it submit again with old values.

I tried to get new viewroot but it also gave me same result.

```
public void reset(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    ViewHandler viewHandler = application.getViewHandler();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, context
            .getViewRoot().getViewId());
    context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
    context.renderResponse(); //Optional

    this.MyBean = new MyBean();
}
```

P.S. After submit I call this method as reset(null);

Comment: what is the scope of the bean ?

Comment: If your scope is viewScope then view must be reset on refreshing page. Please check if it is happening due to autofill entry of browser. And please recheck you managed bean scope.

Comment: @Kush Sahu: Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not issue with refresh, but its the browser which sends previous submitted data. I found some solutions which are pretty good.

- From BalusC blog [POST-Redirect-GET pattern](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html)
- From rohit salecha blog [Liferay Refresh bug](http://www.rohitsalecha.com/370/java/liferay/liferay-refresh-bug/)

Since I am using Liferay, I have to put only

```
<action-url-redirect>true</action-url-redirect>
```

in liferay-portlet.xml like this

```
<portlet>
<portlet-name>booksportlet</portlet-name>
<icon>/icon.png</icon>
<action-url-redirect>true</action-url-redirect>
<instanceable>false</instanceable>
</portlet>
```

So I chose this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the bean to be reset after each request; in that case instead of using the function you can make use of the scope(s) provided by the jsf.

Using the bean in `request` scope

[tutorial on bean scopes](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=472)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But I need the bean in viewscope for one more functionality. Is there not any way to reset viewscope bean.

Comment: @KushSahu : there is always a way, but not the one I know of. wait till BalusC see your question.. ;) :)

Comment: Yeah and I am trying to find out tht solution :) ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the scope of your bean is neither request nor viewscope as you want it to be reset even before view is destroyed.

You can make use of `ConversationScoped` in CDI which will be created when you start the conversation and you can mark it to end by calling `conversation.end()`.

[How does JSF 2 ConversationScope work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788430/how-does-jsf-2-conversationscope-work)

Alternatively , if you want to reset the View Scope bean then you can also do it by using below in your Ajax Event,

```
Map<String, Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                              getViewRoot().getViewMap();
viewMap.put("MyBean",new MyBean());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try this and let you know. :)

Comment: This bean won't be container managed ,remember to call PostConstruct/init method of your bean as container will not call it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's really that simple: Just annotate with @RequestScoped and a button:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean{

public void resetEvent(ActionEvent actionEv) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I need it in view scoped to get some values in other functionalities