# How to extend the lifetime of a bean?

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I need some JSF 2.1.29 advice. I have a bean:

```
public class PlayerCardBean{

    private Integer playerId;
    //GET, SET, Other fileds and methods
}
```

The facelet `playerCard.xhtml` for the bean contains `<a>` tag for redirecting to another page:

```
<a href="javascript://"  
    onclick="openPage('#{request.contextPath}/panels/playerExternalTransactionList.html?playerId=#{playerCardBean.playerId}');">
        <h:outputText value="#msgs['playerCard.externalTransactionList.all']}" />
</a>
```

I need this bean stay alived when the user is on the `playerCard.xhtml` as well as we're redirecting from the `playerCard.xhtml` to by the link within the `<a>` tag.

The view scope is smaller. The bean is going to be destroyed after redirecting.

How can I keep that bean alive when we're redirecting between those two views? By the `<a>` tag and probably by the "back"-button in a browser.

I think that storing the fields within a session is not a good idea because they are not a true-session attributes.

Comment: Don't hack it that way. You should not be insterested in keeping the whole bean alive, but in sending parameters from one bean to another. Just pass them as query parameters or put them in the flash scope.

Comment: @XtremeBiker That's clear, right. But how can I handle back-button click in a browser?

Comment: That subject has been discussed before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application Basically, gain control over what you want to avoid cache over.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of the following two solutions:

1. Use the conversation scope. It requires annotating your bean with the [`@ConversationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html) annotation and you will need to manage (begin and end) the conversation programatically. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792525/3558960) contains some useful sample code.)
2. Use the [`Flash`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html).

Comment: I'm on tomcat, therefore can't use CDI just as simple. But I'm using spring frameowrk. Maybe I can do some with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@ConversationScope`. This scope is started and ended programmatically.
http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-conversationscoped-example

Comment: I'm not on full javaee container. I'm using tomcat.

Comment: You can't reload the properties over the playerId? JSF 2.2 have the @FlowScope http://www.javabeat.net/jsf-2-flowscoped/

Comment: What do you mean reload over? Well, I'm not considering migrating to JSF 2.2.

Comment: The other fields from PlayerCardBean(name?,age?,...). Where do they come from? Database? Otherwise, transfer as query param.

Comment: They come from user and are going to store into a db.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect solution in JSF 2.1 but you can create your own scope which will be good replacement for conversation scope.

More details: 
https://blog.oio.de/2012/07/24/jsf-2-custom-scopes-without-3rd-party-libraries/